# PanelImagen[,0,0,0x0,invalid,layout=java.awt.BorderLayout,alignmentX=0.0,alignmentY=0.0,border=,flags=9,maximumSize=,minimumSize=,preferredSize=]

Tags: java, swing

I have a question, already I programming in eclipse java neon, and I am doing something with tables, and into swing, actually are a component of JTable. Now I need to add to a component in the table an image, and I create a JPanel which name is PanelImagen that guides me to add an images with a rute, etc. When I run the program into the table it says this:

`interfaz.PanelImagen[,0,0,0x0,invalid,layout=java.awt.BorderLayout,alignmentX=0.0,alignmentY=0.0,border=,flags=9,maximumSize=,minimumSize=,preferredSize=]`

and I don't know what this is. I am from Colombia, sorry for my English. This is my code for initializing the table:

```
matriz = new JTable(Circuito.TAMANO_PANEL,Circuito.TAMANO_PANEL);
luces = new PanelImagen[Circuito.TAMANO_PANEL][Circuito.TAMANO_PANEL];

for (int i = 0; i < luces.length; i++) {
    for (int j = 0; j < luces[0].length; j++) {
        luces[i][j] = new PanelImagen("data/imagenes/white.gif");
    }
}
```

Comment: Looks like you're putting JPanels into your JTable. Don't do that. For better help though please ask a more complete question. And please do be careful with your spelling as your post is very hard to understand.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to add an image to a table then you need to:

1. add an `Icon` to the `TableModel`
2. override the `getColumnClass(...)` method of the `TableModel` to tell the table an Icon is being displayed so the table can use an appropriate renderer

For example:

```
import java.awt.*;
import javax.swing.*;
import javax.swing.table.*;

public class TableIcon extends JPanel
{
    public TableIcon()
    {
        Icon aboutIcon = new ImageIcon("about16.gif");
        Icon addIcon = new ImageIcon("add16.gif");
        Icon copyIcon = new ImageIcon("copy16.gif");

        String[] columnNames = {"Picture", "Description"};
        Object[][] data =
        {
            {aboutIcon, "About"},
            {addIcon, "Add"},
            {copyIcon, "Copy"},
        };

        DefaultTableModel model = new DefaultTableModel(data, columnNames)
        {
            //  Returning the Class of each column will allow different
            //  renderers to be used based on Class
            public Class getColumnClass(int column)
            {
                return getValueAt(0, column).getClass();
            }
        };
        JTable table = new JTable( model );
        table.setPreferredScrollableViewportSize(table.getPreferredSize());

        JScrollPane scrollPane = new JScrollPane( table );
        add( scrollPane );
    }

    private static void createAndShowGUI()
    {
        JFrame frame = new JFrame("Table Icon");
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        frame.add(new TableIcon());
        frame.setLocationByPlatform( true );
        frame.pack();
        frame.setVisible( true );
    }

    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable()
        {
            public void run()
            {
                createAndShowGUI();
            }
        });
    }

}
```